# Alignment of matrices using Lyx

Tags: lyx, matrices

I would like to align the entries of this matrix to the left so that every line starts next to the equal sign. Any ideas? Thank you.
[image]

Comment: Use `\begin{array{rcl}`. But the spacing is not good. Why don't you use the `align*` environment (from `amsmath`)? B.t.w.: `cos` is coded in LaTeX as `\cos`.

Comment: but this is not matrix but set of equation which you like to align at `=` :). and i second for *align*` environment from package `amsmath` too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several good reasons for using an `align*` environment (provided by the `amsmath` package) instead of an `array` environment embedded in `\[ ... \]`:

- less typing required
- automatic left-alignment of the material to right of `=` symbols
- material is automatically in display-math mode
- rows are spaced appropriately for display-math material

A possible minimal working example (MWE):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % why use 'latin9'?
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align*' environment

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\cos(3\theta) 
    &= \cos(2\theta)\sin\theta\\
    &= \cos(2\theta)\cos\theta-\sin(2\theta)\sin\theta\\
    &= \cdots
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]